# HTML async data download client side processing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a lot of work that need to be done in the server for a http request. I am thinking of offloading this work to the client by splitting the work into multiple chunks and doing client side processing.

In HTML, I was hoping during page load (while parsing the page), the browser would issue these  chunked queries and store the response in some tag as an attribute.

For example,

http://example.com/doWork
this will just issue doWork page with links like below without doing any work.

```
<div mydata="//example.com/doWork/Work1" />
<div mydata="//example.com/doWork/Work2" />
<div mydata="//example.com/doWork/Work3" />
```

On page load, using javascript I will process the output and compose the page. The benefit I hoped to gain is these individual requests will get load balanced.

I don't want to issue AJAX requests, as it would be slower for page load than browser issuing requests directly while parsing the page links.

Can I use webworkers for this purpose, will that make page load faster?

Comment: anything you do differently in terms of loading the page will probably  slow down what is, at this point, a highly optimized process.

Comment: I understand. But that is the price I have to pay for client side processing. I just want it to be as low as it can be. What is the best way to do this in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a solution. Instead of the divs (which is not a solution anyway) I could use script elements for the doWork request and the server can appropriately issue the work#n's results in each of the JS after actually doing the work. It might be hacky, but that will solve my problem. Thanks!

```
<script async src="//example.com/doWork/Work1.js" />
<script async src="//example.com/doWork/Work2.js" />
<script async src="//example.com/doWork/Work3.js" />
```